# Why do I get this error: _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: flutter, if-statement, casting, nullable, null-safety

I have a column like this:

```
  Column(children: [
    product.videos![product.videoIndex].videoUrl != null &&
            product.videos![product.videoIndex].videoUrl != ""
        ? VideoPlayerWidget(
            videoAddress: product.videos![product.videoIndex].videoUrl)
        : Image.asset('assets/images/video-placeholder.jpg'),
  ]),
```

And I get this error:

```
_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

I know that the variables may be null and that's the reason I put them within a null check if statement, but I don't know why do I get the null check error and how can I pass that?

The Flutter forced me to put `!` after null variables, then it gives me error because of that!

Comment: There's some place that you put "!" after what ends up being a null.  Find that.  Try writing your code entirely without !, and just do the null checks in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `product.videos` is `null`, though you handled the condition if it is `null`, but you are assuring `dart` compiler that `product.videos` can nver be `null` , by using `!` opeartor. Change `!` to `?` meaning , it may be subjected to being `null`, and precautions would be taken if it is `null`.

Change your code by replacing `!` to `?`:

```
 product.videos?[product.videoIndex].videoUrl != null &&
            product.videos?[product.videoIndex].videoUrl != ""
        ? VideoPlayerWidget(
            videoAddress: product.videos![product.videoIndex].videoUrl)
        : Image.asset('assets/images/video-placeholder.jpg'),
```

---

Edit for the comment:

> Could you explain what is the difference between ! and ?. and ? and ??

1. `!` - Saying the compiler value can never be `null`.

```
var val1 = val2! // val2 can never be null
```

2. `?` - Saying the compiler value can be `null`.

```
String? val; // Here val can be potentially null
```

3. `?.` - Access only if not null.

```
object?.prop1; // Here prop1 is accessed only if object is not null
```

4. `??` - Alternate value if the value is null

```
var val1 = val2 ?? val3; // if val2 is null assign va13 to val1
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the difference between ! and ?. and ? and ??

Comment: @best_of_man I have edited the code, might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Looks your `product.videos` itself `null`. So change `!` to `?` in `if` condition.

```dart
Column(children: [
    product.videos?[product.videoIndex].videoUrl != null &&
            product.videos?[product.videoIndex].videoUrl != ""
        ? VideoPlayerWidget(
            videoAddress: product.videos![product.videoIndex].videoUrl)
        : Image.asset('assets/images/video-placeholder.jpg'),
  ]),
```

Comment: Could you explain what is the difference between `!` and `?.` and `?` and `??`

Comment: `!` means that we are sure that will not be null, `?.` means that variable may be null and proceed with null value further, `?` means that result may null. and `??` means that if result is null the use the default value which we given following that.